# WinXP How to Tunnel LPT over USB

Tags: windows-xp, usb, printer

I have a windows program that accesses a device connected to a LPT (1-3) 25 pin port.  The communication is bidirectional, and I suspected the control lines are also accessed directly.

I would like to migrate the device to a machine that does not have a LPT port.

I saw the dos2usb software, but that takes the output (from a DOS program) and 'prints' it formatted for a specific printer.  I need a raw LPT connection, and a cable that provides access to all the control signals.

I do have a USB to 36-pin Centronics that may have the extra signals.  I use it with a vinyl cutter that doesn't like most of the USB dongles.  It comes up as USB001.  Would adding and sharing a generic printer, then mapping LPT1 to the share get me closer?  Would that work for a parallel port scanner?

My preferred solution is a USB cable with a driver that will map it to LPT1, LPT2, or LPT3.

Comment: I highly doubt setting up a printer is going to do anything useful.

Comment: I suspect that would abstract away from what I need

Answer (score 1):

This might depend a lot on the type of access to the parallel port...

If it uses the proper API, a converter should be available... (Or, with some time, you should be able to build one using a microcontroller) (The LUFA library might provide most of the code needed for it)

If the application directly write to the parallel port (if it requires admin rights), it would be a lot harder... (Virtualization MIGHT work, if it converts direct "OUT" assembler commands to something that can work with a USB<-> parallel converter)

Comment: Thank you for the insights.  I'll have to look closer at what the app requires.  Assuming it's using the proper API, is there a way to map LPT1 to a USB001 IEEE-1284 device?